# How to write the parameters of a replace() call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am currently porting my web app codes from PHP to JS.

I am having an issue with this regex. from PHP

```
/\(\d*\)|\/\(P\)\//
```

used like this

```
preg_replace('/\(\d*\)|\/\(P\)\//', '', $string);
```

how can I convert this to work on JS ?

```
str.replace();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the problem?? str.replace() ?

Comment: RegExp is a native feature on Javascript, so you don't need the quotes, just `/^$/.test("string")`.

Comment: Drop the appostrophes and at a `/g` flag if you want to perform a global regex! ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing really special. PHP regex syntax is very much the same as in JavaScript:

```
str = str.replace(/\(\d*\)|\/\(P\)\//g, "");
```

You can find more information about regular expressions in JavaScript in this manual from *MDN*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Comment: yes, nothing really special other than the /g flag. thank you!

Comment: The /s flag is valid PHP but not JS.

Comment: JavaScript regex does not support conditional constructs, whereas PHP does.