# How to convert a php regex to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

What's the best way to convert php regex to javascript ?

What i'm trying to do is to extract all links with or without protocol and this php regex is doing the perfect job but i'm having difficulty doing same regex in javascript.

Here's my code:

```
$re = '~\b(?:https?://)?(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b~';
$str = 'ola mech.us por.we number site.com';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Here's what i've tried but there's syntax error i can't fix. Just starting javascript and i can't fix syntax error

```
const regex = /\b(?:https?://)?(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b/g;
const str = 'ola teech. por.we number site.com';
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the *almost best* way you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert PHP regex to JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399019/how-to-convert-php-regex-to-javascript-regex)

Comment: Other than asking someone to do it for you (2nd best), the first best would be to learn regular expression syntax.

Comment: I've tried this but there's syntax in my code and i don't know how to fix it:

Comment: const regex = /\b(?:https?://)?(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b/g;
const str = 'ola teech. por.we number site.com';
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- As in JavaScript you cannot choose the delimiter of the regex literal, and it is fixed to `/`, you must escape those within your regular expression.
- The case-insensitive flag `(?i:` needs to be in the terminating modifier part of the regex literal, and will then apply to the whole regular expression, which shouldn't be an issue.

So:

```
const regex = /\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:([a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b/gi;
```

Further more, there is no possibility for a zero length match with this regex, so the part in your code that deals with that scenario is not needed.

```js
const regex = /\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:([a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b/gi;
const str = 'ola teech. por.we number site.com';
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But adding those backlash result in "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?i:[a-z]+\.)+)[^\s,]+\b/: Invalid group" error

Comment: I had already updated my answer in that respect. And a runnable snippet is there now.